# Returning an error when there are more items in an iterator than expected

Tags: rust

`Option` has [`ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) that maps `Some` to `Ok` and `None` to `Err`, *e.g.*:

```
let foo = iterator.next().ok_or(MyError)?;
```

If I want to verify that the iterator returns `None` after already taking the necessary items (an expected number of them), what should I use? I'm looking for something that returns `Ok` if `None`, and a custom error in other cases:

```
let _ = iterator.next().the_method_i_search(|elem| MyError::MyCase(elem))?;
```

I know I can do:

```
if let Some(elem) = iterator.next() {
    return Err(MyError::MyCase(elem));
}
```

but I like the succinctness of the `?` operator and method chaining in Rust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the original problem is to fetch N elements from an iterator and raise an error when the iterator still has more elements after that. I solved this first by creating a new iterator adaptor `TakeExactly`, which yields an iterator of `Result`s. After the first `n` retrievals, the iterator will start returning the items as errors.

```
use std::iter::Iterator;

struct TakeExactly<I> {
    it: I,
    n: usize,    
}

impl<I> Iterator for TakeExactly<I>
where 
    I: Iterator
{
    type Item = Result<I::Item, I::Item>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match (self.it.next(), self.n) {
            (None, _) => None,
            (Some(x), 0) => Some(Err(x)),
            (Some(x), _) => {
                self.n -= 1;
                Some(Ok(x))
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Let's also make a utility function:

```
fn take_exactly<I: IntoIterator>(it: I, n: usize) -> TakeExactly<I::IntoIter> {
    TakeExactly {
        it: it.into_iter(),
        n,
    }
}
```

With that done, we can easily collect the expected number of items like this:

```
let x: Result<Vec<_>, _> = take_exactly(vec![5, 4, 3], 2).collect();
assert_eq!(x, Err(3));

let x: Result<String, _> = take_exactly("Rustacean".chars(), 9).collect();
assert_eq!(x, Ok("Rustacean".to_string()));
```

This is possible because `Result` implements `FromIterator` by delegating the collection of all `Ok` values, yielding the first error if one was found.

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=346c879a0a1dd084757065837756b18b&version=stable)